# create flows button using JavaScript in salesforce

Tags: javascript, custom-button, visual-workflow, flow, visual-flows

I want to display flows in lead object  direct button no need to use visualforce pages,i think it is possible in javascript can you please suggest me...

Thanks,
Bhaskar

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.  You will obviously have to substitute in your values like your flow name, and the parameters, if any, you want to pass in, but this should get you started.

```
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

String base = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl();
var url = {!base}+encodeURI('/flow/FLOW_NAME&SOME_PARAM={!sObject.Id}&retURL=/{!sObject.Id}');

window.open(url);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the code be var url = base+encodeURI(...) without the {}s around base?

Answer (score 0):

It work me fine

```
{!RequireScript('/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js')}

var url = encodeURI('/flow/FLOW_NAME?SOME_PARAM={!sObject.Id}&retURL={!sObject.Id}');

window.open(url);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm trying to use this and get an error stating the there is no field called Base..
Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

```
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

String base = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl();
var urlToOpen = {!base}+encodeURI('/flow/Opportunity_Closed_Won_Create_Service_Contract?var_Oppty_Id={!Opportunity.Id}&retURL=/{!Opportunity.Id}');
var Stage = "{!Opportunity.StageName}";
var RecordTypeId = "{!Opportunity.RecordType}";
var WelcomeCallCompleted = "{!Opportunity.Welcome_Call_Completed__c}";

if (Stage ! 'Won') 
{ 
alert('You cannot create a Service Contract unless the Opportunity is 'Won' - please review the Opportunity Stage in order to proceed'); 
} 
else if (Stage == 'Won' && RecordTypeId == '01211000000CxLW') && WelcomeCallCompleted == '')
{ 
alert('You cannot create a Service Contract for a New Customer Opportunity unless the Welcome Call has been completed -  please review the Opportunity Welcome Call field in order to proceed';

}
 else  
 {
  window.open(urlToOpen);
}
```

Comment: I did as suggested, and now I'm getting an 'Unexpected Identifier' error..any one can help me?